# Why does the resource file format change after syncing from Perforce?

Tags: c#, dll, perforce

I have an ACTIVE TEMPLATE LIBRARY project for to be used as the starting point for
writing your Dynamic Link Library (DLL).
It has a resource header: Resource.h (This is the standard header file that defines resource IDs.)

It originally looks like this:

```
//{{NO_DEPENDENCIES}}
// Microsoft Visual C++ generated include file.
// Used by MyProject.rc
//
#define IDS_PROJNAME                    100
#define IDR_MyProject                 101
#define IDB_MyProjectFILT             106
#define IDR_MyProjectFILT             107

// Next default values for new objects
// 
#ifdef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
#ifndef APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS
#define _APS_NEXT_RESOURCE_VALUE        201
#define _APS_NEXT_COMMAND_VALUE         32768
#define _APS_NEXT_CONTROL_VALUE         201
#define _APS_NEXT_SYMED_VALUE           108
#endif
#endif
```

Now, after I sync this file from the depot using Perforce (P4 client and not command-line), the resource file changes to this:

```
//{{NO_DEPENDENCIES}}
਍⼀⼀ 䴀椀挀爀漀猀漀昀琀 嘀椀猀甀愀氀 䌀⬀⬀ 最攀渀攀爀愀琀攀搀 椀渀挀氀甀搀攀 昀椀氀     攀⸀ഀഀ
// Used by MyProject.rc
਍⼀⼀ഀഀ
#define IDS_PROJNAME                    100
਍⌀搀攀昀椀渀攀 䤀䐀刀开䄀唀䐀䤀伀匀倀䠀䔀刀䔀                 ㄀　㄀ഀഀ
#define IDB_MyProjectFILT             106
਍⌀搀攀昀椀渀攀 䤀䐀刀开䄀唀䐀䤀伀匀倀䠀䔀刀䔀䘀䤀䰀吀             ㄀　㜀ഀഀ

਍⼀⼀ 一攀砀琀 搀攀昀愀甀氀琀 瘀愀氀甀攀猀 昀漀爀 渀攀眀 漀戀樀攀挀琀猀ഀഀ
// 
਍⌀椀昀搀攀昀 䄀倀匀吀唀䐀䤀伀开䤀一嘀伀䬀䔀䐀ഀഀ
#ifndef APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS
਍⌀搀攀昀椀渀攀 开䄀倀匀开一䔀堀吀开刀䔀匀伀唀刀䌀䔀开嘀䄀䰀唀䔀        ㈀　㄀ഀഀ
#define _APS_NEXT_COMMAND_VALUE         32768
਍⌀搀攀昀椀渀攀 开䄀倀匀开一䔀堀吀开䌀伀一吀刀伀䰀开嘀䄀䰀唀䔀         ㈀　㄀ഀഀ
#define _APS_NEXT_SYMED_VALUE           108
਍⌀攀渀搀椀昀ഀഀ
#endif
਍
```

Does it have to do something with my project properties? Or, it has got something to do with my P4 Client?
Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like the file may have been added with an incorrect file type. Have you tried sync'ing the file from other machines? Do other users of the server have the same problem with this file? Is this the only file that has this problem? Perhaps you should delete the file and re-add it, paying close attention to the file type that is assigned to the file (see 'p4 add -t' in the documentation)

Comment: Thank you for responding. The file is added as ktext (with base filetype as text) and this is happening on other machines and to any user who syncs this file from the server. This is the only file which is having problem. I have tried re-adding, but unfortunately it did not work.

Comment: If it's happening to all users and all clients, then it definitely has nothing to do with your particular client or your particular workstation's properties, but is due to something about the way the file is being handled by the server. Is the strange display always the same? It's quite odd that it's every other line being mis-displayed. Is that always the pattern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is from a long time ago, but I've just had this exact same problem (it was an MFC application, rather than C# though). The problem was the file type being set to 'text'. Changing it to UTF16 fixed the problem.